# How an assembler instruction could not read the memory it is placed at

Tags: windows, exception, memory-management, x86

Using some software in Windows XP that works as a Windows service and doing a restart from the logon screen I see an infamous error message

> The instruction at "00x..." referenced memory at "00x...". The memory
>   could not be read.

I reported the problem to the developers, but looking at the message once again, I noticed that the addresses are the same. So

> The instruction at "00xdf3251" referenced memory at "00xdf3251". The memory
>   could not be read.

Whether this is a bug in the program or not, but what is the state of the memory/access rights or something else that prevents an instruction from reading the memory it is placed. Is it something specific to services?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess there was an attempt to execute an instruction at the address 0xdf3251 and that location wasn't backed up by a readable and executable page of memory (perhaps, completely unmapped).

If that's the case, the exception (page fault, in fact) originates from that instruction and the exception handler has its address on the stack (the location to return to, in case the exception can be somehow resolved and the faulting instruction restarted when the handler returns). And that's the first address you're seeing.

The `CR2` register that the page fault handler reads, which is the second address you're seeing, also has the same address because it has to contain the address of an inaccessible memory location irrespective of whether the page fault has been caused by:

- complete absence of mapping (there's no page mapped at all)
- lack of write permission (the page is read-only)
- lack of execute permission (the page has the no-execute bit set) OR
- lack of kernel privilege (the page is marked as accessible only in the kernel)

and irrespective of whether it was during a data access or while fetching an instruction (the latter being our case).

That's how you can get the instruction and memory access addresses equal.

Most likely the code had a bug resulting in a memory corruption and some pointer (or a return address on the stack) was overwritten with a bogus value pointing to an inaccessible memory location. And then one way or the other the CPU was directed to continue execution there (most likely using one of these instructions: `jmp`, `call`, `ret`). There's also a chance of having a race condition somewhere.

Comment: Nice explanation, probably this was the case here.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of crash is most typically caused by stack corruption.  A very common kind is a stack buffer overflow.  Write too much data in an array stored on the stack and it overwrites a function's return address with the data.  When the function then returns, it jumps to the bogus return address and the program falls over because there's no code at the address.  They'll have a hard time fixing the bug since there's no easy way to find out where the corruption occurred.

This is a rather infamous kind of bug, it is a major attack vector for malware.  Since it can commandeer a program to jump to arbitrary code with data.  You ought to have a sitdown with these devs and point this out, it is a major security risk.  The cure is easy enough, they should update their tools.  Countermeasures against buffer overflow are [built into the compilers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dbf701c%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) these days.

Comment: Unfortunately, the countermeasures aren't guaranteed to catch every corruption that can lead to this. What if it's a use-after-freed bug?

Comment: A use-after-free crash doesn't cause this kind of AV, code and data addresses will be different.

Comment: Suppose you have a dynamically allocated structure with a function pointer in it and the program calls a function through that pointer. All is dandy until you free the structure but continue using the stale pointer to it. And then the memory where the structure used to be gets overwritten by something else newly allocated.

Comment: Hmya, nothing is impossible when all you know is a crash address.  That's why he needs to sit down with the devs to ensure the 99% odds for this kind of crash are eliminated.